# How to make text align work for strong tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to justify the text inside the `<strong>`tag. I have added `strong {text-align: justify;}` which didn't work. Here is the link where I'm trying to run this example.
https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/abNQeoL. I also added `strong {font-weight: normal;}` and that worked. Only text-align is giving a hand. I don't want html to be changed even a bit. I want only css to be changed. Can anyone help me regarding this? My previous two questions were also regarding this issue but they were closed as there were no minimum details. I think above link gives you the sufficient requirements.

Comment: You can your expected output

Comment: Why not use better tag, such as <p> and style it using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to strong instead of `font-weight: normal;` work perfectly :)

> Because, `<strong>` is an **inline element** per default. Meaning it has **no width or height** on its own but rather is exactly as big as its content. So you can try to add `display` property **inline-block** or **block**.

```
strong {
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;// also works with display:block
}
```

```css
strong {
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
think I have more power than he does. I think I could string together the wrestling and the grappling and the striking better than he can, and it will be the best fight
<br /><br />
<strong>WBC heavyweight champion Tyson Fury has applied pressure on his domestic rival, Anthony Joshua, to bypass any further obligations that stand in the way of a 2021 showdown.

  Fury is going to face Deontay Wilder in a trilogy fight on the tentative date of December 19.</strong>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specifie The CSS **display:block** or **display:inline-block**   property  to render the HTML element to box element.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would apply `text-align: justify;` to a parent block level element.

As you're applying it to an inline element (the `strong` tag) you need to set this to `display: block;` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
strong {
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
think I have more power than he does. I think I could string together the wrestling and the grappling and the striking better than he can, and it will be the best fight
<br /><br />
<strong>WBC heavyweight champion Tyson Fury has applied pressure on his domestic rival, Anthony Joshua, to bypass any further obligations that stand in the way of a 2021 showdown.

  Fury is going to face Deontay Wilder in a trilogy fight on the tentative date of December 19.</strong>
```